# Delphi XE6 - How to show TWordApplication in my TForm instead of its own window

Tags: delphi, ms-word, ole

Does anybody have an idea how to connect TWordApplication to my TForm window to get under control the location, because since Office 2007 Word opens on the background and user must click to its icon on taskbar and it makes confusing a bit. I would get also posibility to add some MenuItems to do some other specific tasks such as insert texts, ...

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: I doubt that this is possible. Cross process parenting is not supported. It is only still present for compat with 16 bit Windows.

Comment: So, it seems, that I will need to adapt it to OleContainer which can be placed to my form?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, it still **is** supported. But clearly in this case OLE to the rescue.

Comment: TOleContainer will allow you to embed it  in your form, but it does not allow you to add menu items. You'd have to write a Word plug-in to do that for you, or do it via Word macros.